# Why does inequality test eliminate NULL values?

Tags: sql, oracle

After I added `c.category <> 'AGILE'` to the query below, the results set stopped including `NULL` values for `c.category`.  How can I get rows with a `NULL` c.category back in my result set, without doing a `UNION`?

```
select 
            p.number,
            p.method
            ,sum(p.amount) AS amount
            ,count(*) AS count,c.category
from        payments p
inner join  headers a
      on    p.name = a.name
inner join  customer c
      on    c.number = p.number
  and       a.status = 'APPROVED'
  and       a.type IN ('REGULAR', 'TRANSFER', 'OTHER')
  and       c.category <> 'AGILE'
group by 
            p.payment_method
            ,p.cust_number
            ,c.u_cust_category
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL` is neither equal to nor unequal to any particular value.  If you want to include NULL values, you would want something like

```
and(   c.category <> 'AGILE'
    or c.category IS NULL)
```

Comment: +1 "NULL is neither equal to nor unequal to any particular value". Not even to itself.

Answer (score 2):

This simply works:

```
(c.category <> 'AGILE' OR c.category IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
AND (c.category IS NULL OR c.category <> 'AGILE')
```

Here's another:

```
AND NVL(c.category, 'foo') <> 'AGILE'
```